# PHP MySQL if time is 5 minutes more or over then the stored time

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I want to the script to delete the row if the difference between a timestamp that is stored in the db and the current time is 5 minutes or more.

**Example**

A row in db has 2011/12/25 10:00
the current time is 2001/12/25 10:06

I want it to remove the db row.

Comment: This is very broad. Which part are you struggling with? Can you show the code you currently have to query the database etc.?

Comment: I think what your looking for is some type of cron job.

Comment: @Russell You really want to be double-checking your accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Why the cron suggestions? You can easily call the very easy delete statement on every page view. At the moment that becomes a bottlenecks (and then we're talking about either a massively underengineered table structure or a very busy site), it may become appropriate to see why the query is so slow. Run an explain query, apply some indexes, and so on. If the problem then still exists, it could be that it's simply too much work to let a visitors wait for, and then it's time for cron.

Until then, simply execute the following query on each page view:

```
delete 
from 
    YourTable 
where 
    adddate(YourDateTimeColumn, interval 5 minute) < now()
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above is slightly wrong. It should be

```
delete 
from 
    YourTable 
where 
    adddate(YourDateTimeColumn, interval 5 minute) < now()
```

There was an s on minute, it shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Linux, you could write a [chron job](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) that executes a php(or almost any other language) script that does this. As far as I know, a database will not have this sort of functionality built in, you need to write code that actively does it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Woops cron lol, hm, always thought it was named after [Chronos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronos), like many time based things are, my mistake. Wonder how that never clicked, I've written tons of them :S

Answer (score -3):

try this, not tested tho:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$id = $result['id'];
$timestamp = strtotime($result['timestamp']);
if($timestamp < time()-300){
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=".$id."");
}
```

Comment: Pulling *all* entries from the database into PHP to then *maybe* delete the first entry? -1000

Comment: Well, given a test case containing only one item older than five minutes and that item being the first entry, it'll work.