# Deleting everything in database less than a number

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I would like to run a query that would delete every row in a database that had the ID of less than a figure.

The context I want to use it in, is running a PHP CRON job every 24 hours that will delete all rows with values in the 'time' column that are LESS THAN time();

Putting it in to another context: I want to run a query that will delete every row that has an ID of ~10.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL if time is 5 minutes more or over then the stored time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528573/php-mysql-if-time-is-5-minutes-more-or-over-then-the-stored-time)

Comment: You do know what a `WHERE` clause is and that you can use them in `DELETE` queries, right? Or do we have to start explaining the basics of SQL?

Comment: None - I was wondering how it could be done.

Comment: What do you mean by  "an ID of ~10" ?

Comment: Yes I do know what a WHERE clause is and the fact they can be used in a DELETE query, but it's how to use to delete the rows that are less than a certain number.

Comment: An ID of less than ten.

Comment: `DELETE FROM table WHERE id < 10`...?!

Comment: Did you heard about SQL language ? I mean, did you tried something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you are not very familiar with SQL.  This is a simple `delete` statement:

```
delete from t
    where id < 10;
```

This assumes that by "database", you really mean "table".  It also makes some other assumptions about foreign key references in other tables.  Because the question seems so basic, I am guessing these are not issues.

However, I would recommend that you study up a bit on databases if you are going to use them in your applications.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive help- works, thank you.